# Listeners Agents Firebase not only in ComponentDidMount Method

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to set a database agent listener after a state change? I mean normally we used to set it on `componentDidMount` method. But I want to call it depending on a state.

I want my user to get a list of specific data, and not all the node. That data should not "listen", directly on app Start, but after the app takes a specific state.

```
firebase.database().ref("myRef")
    .on("value", (snap)=>{ 
        console.log(snap.val()) 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a function and calling it when state changes like:

```
 functionForstateChange(){
    //call this function when you want to change your state.
   //setState here and make your required state changes if you need.
   this.functionForDatabase();    //call the function here
 }
 functionForDatabase(){
    //set your required database code here
 }
```